# Why Spring Data JPA Specification interface extends Serializable?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am curious about why Spring/JPA has made [`Specification`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specification.html) interface `Serializable`? I understand that jpa entities should be serializable and jpa `Specification` uses these entities. But `Specification` just implements query builder, why make it `Serializable`?  -

```
public interface Specification<T> extends Serializable
```

Comment: If you follow up on the change on GitHub, you'll find out it refactors an older implementation which involved both an interface and a class. The refactored version leverages Java 8 (default methods directly in the new interface). In the original code, the class was made serializable due to remote calls - see [DATAJPA-523](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-523). Obviously, this feature had to be preserved and hence it's reflected in the Specification interface.